# ask for~ / ask someone to give ~

Tags: word-usage

I saw a girl studying at a coffee shop and I thought she was beautiful.And a couple of weeks after I'd seen her studying at the coffee shop, I saw her dancing really hard at a club, when I thought she was so attractive that I

> 1. could not help but **ask for** her phone number.
> 2. could not help but **ask her to give me** her phone number.

I'm perfectly comfortable using "ask someone to ~" pattern, but I'd like to know if I can use "ask for~" in this context.

Comment: yes, I thought I could use "can not help ~ing / but ~" pattern here to imply that I have no choice but to approach her and ask her to give me number. because she is attractive enough for me to do that.

Comment: Are you sure about *dancing hard*? how one dance hard?

Comment: You much use *AND* in your sentences. I would write *I saw a girl studying at a coffee shop. I thought she was beautiful. A couple of weeks later, I saw her dancing at a club. At that moment I thought she was so attractive that I couldn't help but ask her for phone number*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are correct,

however, when you ask someone to get something, the pattern is **ask somebody for something**, example:

> I asked John for his number.

if you say **ask for something** as

> I asked for her number

it may also mean you asked the other people to give you her number